# bash stdout redirection in a for loop

Tags: bash, loops, stdout

**Possible duplicate**

Hello,

I'm struggling with output redirection within a bash for loop. I have several similar bash scripts, each scripts being launched on a different input file. The scripts called a tool with a few arguments.

The bash scripts are like this :

```
my_tool --input input_file --arg1 arg1_name --arg2 arg2_name > output_dir/result_X.dat
```

`X` being a string which is unique for each script.

I run all of them in a for loop :

```
for script in scripts_dir/*.sh
do
    bash $script
done
```

However, the stdout of each run still display on the terminal. The specified output files are created, but empty. How I can solve that ? I found other questions on stackoverflow where the answer is a redirection of the full loop in one big output file, but I'd like to avoid that.

If I replace `> output_dir/result_X.dat` by `> /dev/null` : the standard outputs display on the terminal

If I replace `> output_dir/result_X.dat` by ` 2> /dev/null : nothing is displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the program isn't writing to standard *error*?

Comment: What is `an_identifier_defined_in_the_script.dat`?   The shell parses that line before the script is even executed, so if you are trying to define the name of the output file in the script, this will not work.

Comment: @WilliamPursell it's simply a string for ID. The script contains a command line for another tool, and the string changes for every run (but there is a different bash file for every run, so the ID strings are already written)

Comment: @Amessihel I just tried with one file : nothing displays on the terminal, but the output file is still empty :/

Comment: @Micawber : so the code you are having issues with is not the code you have shown.  You should be able to reproduce your issue in a minimal way.  What happens if you execute `my_script_or_program > /dev/null`?  Very likely the loop is irrelevant.  Given that `2> /dev/null` gives you no output, it is pretty clear that all of your script's output is being written to stderr.

Comment: OK it's a bit confusing for me, I'' do some tests and update the question with details

Comment: I added `2>&1` after `> output_dir/result_X.dat` and it seems to work fine now. Can anyone explain shy ?

Comment: Yes, it is because your program is outputting to standard error! I think we said this before? `2>&1`says redirect stderr to stdout. You could equally put `2>output/result_X.dat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start `my_tool`, there are normally 3 file-descriptors available in the tool:

- STDIN
- STDOUT
- STDERR

STDIN is used for input, and therefore irrelevant for this question. STDOUT is used for standard output. This is file-descriptor 1. If you do

```
ls 1> /dev/null
```

the STDOUT of ls is written to `/dev/null`. If you do not add the `1`, as in `ls > /dev/null`, it is assumed that you mean STDOUT.

STDERR is used as standard output for error messages, in the broadest sense of the word. The number of STDERR is 2.

Using `ls` instead of your `my_command`, `ls > file` will put the listing in the `file`. `ls /non_existing_dir_ > file` will put the STDOUT of `ls` in the `file`. But there is no output on STDOUT, and because STDERR is not redirected, it will be send to the terminal.

So, to conclude,

```
ls . /non_existing_dir 2>stderr >stdout
```

will put the directory listing of `.` in the file `stdout` and the error for the non-existing directory in `stderr`.

With `2>&1` you redirect the output of filedescriptor2 (STDERR) to file descriptor 1 (SDTOUT).

To complicate things a bit, you can add other file descriptor numbers. For example:

```
exec 3>file
```

will put the output of file descriptor 3 (which is newly created) in `file`. And

```
ls 1>&3
```

will then redirect the output of file descriptor 1 to file descriptor 3, effectively putting the output of `ls` in `file`.

Comment: I know part of that already, but I had not clue this program was sending the output to stderr ! Silly me.